# Django Admin hides names and shows (table_name object)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I am fairly new to django admin. I am trying to manage my table contents from the admin section for table created with the following models:

```
class subject(models.Model):
   subject_id = models.CharField(max_length=12, unique=True)
   name =  models.CharField(max_length=25)

class subject_date(models.Model):
   sub_id = models.ForeignKey(subject)
   date =  models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

I have added my subjects to the **subject table** and now I want to add subject dates to the **subject_date table** from the admin section. Because of the one to many relationship I get a drop-down list under **sub_id** of all the subjects I added in the **subject table**. the problem is that the drop-down list has all the contents written as follows:

> **subject object**

This makes it impossible for me to see which subject I am dealing with. Can anyone please help me with this if its an issue that can be fixed.

Comment: Define `__str__` methods on the models (or `__unicode__` if you're still using Python 2).

Comment: Where do I define it. An example please is you may

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your models.py define `__str__` and return your name.

```
class subject(models.Model):
   subject_id = models.CharField(max_length=12, unique=True)
   name =  models.CharField(max_length=25)

   def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```